# First row error with @rownum mysql

Tags: mysql, rownum

I am trying to generate rownum for a mysql query.
This is my code.

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 rowno, (`plgap_nos`.`no_id` - 1) AS `no_id`
from `plgap_nos`,
     (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
limit 0, 10
```

While everything works fine, the rownum of first row shoes 1621 and not 0.

It tried with a differnt code as below. still same error persists.

```
select COALESCE(@rownum:=@rownum+1,0) rank,
       (`cnxnifty_plgap_nos`.`no_id` - 1) AS `no_id`
from `money_database`.`cnxnifty_plgap_nos`,
     (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
limit 0, 10
```

It seems i am committing some silly error which i am not being able to figure.
Can anyone help.

Additional info- this is how the data looks-
Rank     no_id
1621     0
1           7
2           18
3           21
4           33
5           37
6           45

Comment: You need to add an `ORDER BY` clause in your query, otherwise row order and consequently `@rownum` values are going to be arbitrary.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - Please see the data snapshot i have added in the main post. While every rownum and no_id are in same order, the rowno for 1st record is 1621.

Comment: This is because row with `no_id = 0` is *not* processed first. You **must** add `ORDER BY no_id` if you need this row to have `@row_num=1`.

Comment: i get the same result even after ordering by no_id.

Comment: Is your actual query the same as the one posted here? I cannot reproduce the issue on my end.

Comment: Why are you "generating" this? Is this safe from classic concurrency issues or not?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior mentioned. Here [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecb4b/3) test.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to be clear.  The following code exhibits the same problem?

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as rowno, (p.no_id - 1) AS no_id
from plgap_nos p cross join
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params
order by p.no_id
limit 0, 10;
```

The variable assignment in the `select` should be executed *after* the `from` initialization.  I have not seen MySQL do initializations in the wrong order (which would be one reason for the behavior you are seeing).

The changes I made to the query (`cross join` instead of comma, `order by`, and table alias) should not affect the result set.  However, the scoping semantics of `cross join` are different from the `,`, so there is a small, small possibility that the `cross join` might end up fixing the problem.